# Автоинкремент и автозаполнение

Tags: база-данных, visual-studio

Я внутри VS сделал БД. Но вот беда, я не знаю, как сделать там, чтобы поле `ID` само увеличивалось, а поле `Data` заполнялось автоматически? БД только в VS, без phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 2):

Уточните, пожалуйста, вопрос: что значит "поле Data заполнялось автоматически"?

Если БД MS SQL, то так:

```
create table mytable (   
  id int identity(1,1),   
  data <тип данных> default '<значение по-умолчанию>',  
  constraint pk_id primary key (id) 
)
```

Comment: Хочется, чтобы поле `ID` увеличивалось на 1 при каждой добавленой записи.

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал создавать таблицы через SQL, а не через конструктор VS/SSMS. Поставьте в настройках столбца автоувеличение(не помню где именно этот флажок), по поводу автоматической даты: ставьте значение по-умолчанию GETDATE()

Comment: Да но вот беда, я не умею работать с SQL в C#, да и выводить таблицу в программе думаю не очень удобно будет, а в VS очень удобно.

Comment: Бедняга, какая каша в голове...

Вы хоть различаете между собой такие сущности как: СУБД, БД, Инструменты для работы с БД, SQL, Визуальный конструктор, Среда разработки, Язык программирования???

Похоже вы используете MS SQL редакции Compact Edition или Express Edition с которой VS работает "прозрачно".

По вашему вопросу - почитайте основы SQL и большая часть вопросов у вас решится сама собой. И еще почитайте хотя бы в Wikipedia определения тех терминов, что я привел выше.

С уважением.